# Removing Selected Item from List Box

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, listbox, entity-framework-6

I am trying to remove an entry from my `ListBox` when clicking on my Delete Quote button. Now the issue that I have is that **nothing** is happening when I click on my button. There are also **no** errors what so ever.

Here is a code snippet:

```
    private void btnDeleteQuote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbxQuoteNumber.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
        var quote = (ListBoxViewItem<Quote>)lbxQuoteNumber.SelectedItem;
        foreach (var qu in quote.Item.QuoteNumber) //<<-- I can even remove this line, but it still does not work
            lbxQuoteNumber.Items.Remove(quote);
    }
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong here, because I cannot understand what is going on. I have restarted my application and the entries that I "deleted" are still showing and they are not removed from my database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**EDIT:** Here is my coding where I populate my `lbxQuoteNumber`

```
    private void lbxRepresentatives_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbxQuoteNumber.Items.Clear();
        if (lbxRepresentatives.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        var rep = (ListBoxViewItem<Represetative>)lbxRepresentatives.SelectedItem;
        foreach (var qu in rep.Item.Quotes)
            lbxQuoteNumber.Items.Add(new ListBoxViewItem<Quote>(qu, qu.QuoteNumber));
    }
```

I am referencing all my classes/tables from another web service that I am running in the background. Might this be the problem and should I create a **delete** function(code first) there, or should it be fine to delete my data from this program where my `ListBox` is on?

Comment: This cast is probably not what you want - `(ListBoxViewItem<Quote>)lbxQuoteNumber.SelectedItem;`.  Here you are casting the list box, not the selected item.  Careful with parentheses. Your enumeration variable isn't used also.

Comment: Where is you delete from database action?

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen - Sorry, I thought `Items.Remove` was supposed to remove the item from the database as well. Is there a good way to remove it from the database? I am not very good at c# sorry!

Comment: Can you update your post on how you read the items from the database and filling the `ListBox`?

Comment: Yes I will update it quick :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not commiting the changes to the DB:

```
lbxQuoteNumber.SaveChanges();
```

after removing the items.

EDIT: Or call it on the proper object, if "lbxQuoteNumber" isn't your DB context object :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am getting the error: _Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges' and no extension method 'SaveChanges' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_

Comment: Wait, where exactly do you remove any stuff from the DB? It seems like 'lbxQuoteNumber.Items.Remove(quote)' only removes items from the listbox.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that `Items.Remove` will remove the item from my database as well!

Comment: How can I remove the data from my database then? Sorry, I am quite new to C#, so I do not always understand how things work. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to also remove it from your database, since you didn't provide any code with how you handle your database ill show you what I do.

```
dbContext.Quotes.Remove(quoteObject);
dbContaxt.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try shortly!

Comment: Don't create a new context to do this, you need to use the same context you used to load the objects into the form

Comment: Ok I will do so when I get back on my main PC. I will keep you updated with everything once It's tested. Thank you for you input so far! :)